# Changing visibility of ToolbarItem - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I want to fill collection of `ToolbarItems` from `XAML`, but change visibility of some `ToolbarItem` from view model.

I implemented `BasePage` with some wrapper around `ToolbarItems` collection:

```
public class BasePage : ContentPage
{
    public IList<CustomToolbarItem> CustomToolbar { get; private set; }

    public BasePage()
    {
        var items = new ObservableCollection<CustomToolbarItem>();
        items.CollectionChanged += ToolbarItemsChanged;

        CustomToolbar = items;
    }

    private void ToolbarItemsChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToolbarItems.Clear();

        foreach (var item in CustomToolbar)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged += OnToolbarItemPropertyChanged;
            if (item.IsVisible)
            {
                ToolbarItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnToolbarItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == CustomToolbarItem.IsVisibleProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            UpdateToolbar();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateToolbar()
    {
        foreach (var item in CustomToolbar)
        {
            if (item.IsVisible)
            {
                ToolbarItems.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                ToolbarItems.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        ToolbarItems.Clear();
        CustomToolbar.Clear();
        foreach (var item in CustomToolbar)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged -= OnToolbarItemPropertyChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

`CustomToolbarItem.cs`:

```
public class CustomToolbarItem : ToolbarItem
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsVisibleProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsVisible),
                                    typeof(bool),
                                    typeof(CustomToolbarItem),
                                    true);
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsVisibleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

How I use it in `XAML`:

```
<local:BasePage x:Name="Page"
            xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ToolbarExtensionSample;assembly=ToolbarExtensionSample"
            x:Class="ToolbarExtensionSample.SubPage">


  <local:BasePage.CustomToolbar>
    <local:CustomToolbarItem Name="Alloha"
                             IsVisible="{Binding IsItemVisible, Source={x:Reference Page}}"/>
  </local:BasePage.CustomToolbar>

  <Button Text="Click!"
          Clicked="OnButtonClicked"/>
</local:BasePage>
```

My code is working, but I'm wondering is it okay for performance? Maybe, exists some better solution.
Thanks in advance for suggestions to improvements or better approaches.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, is your code working? What are the specific things you want to improve.  Add the specific questions to your question above. Your question seems a little vague.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. You clear `ToolbarItems` and `CustomToolbar` when page dissapearing, this causes problem: when you show next page and then go back, you won't see your items anymore, because they were cleared.
2. Handlers `OnToolbarItemPropertyChanged` will not be removed in foreach cycle, because you clear list before this cycle.